# Angular 8 Click event not being received

Tags: angular

The method where the event is emitted works fine, but the subscribed method doesn't fire. Here is the relevant code - sorry for including so much, but I felt it was necessary for context; the key lines are the ones with double asterisks because bold doesn't work inside code blocks:

> app.component.html

```html
<div class="container">
  <app-header
    (menuFired)="onMenuFired($event)"
    ></app-header>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <app-recipe-book *ngIf="isRecipesSelected()"></app-recipe-book>

      <app-shopping-list *ngIf="isShoppingListSelected()"></app-shopping-list>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { EventSource } from './header/header.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'course-project';
  currentSelection: EventSource = EventSource.Recipes;

  onMenuFired(eventData: EventSource) {
    **console.log("This doesn't work");**
    this.currentSelection = eventData;
  }

  isRecipesSelected() {
    return (this.currentSelection ===
      EventSource.Recipes);
  }

  isShoppingListSelected() {
    return (this.currentSelection ===
      EventSource.ShoppingList);
  }
}
```

> header.component.html

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button
        type="button"
        class="navbar-toggle"
        (click)="collapsed = !collapsed"
        ><span
          class="icon-bar"
          *ngFor="let iconBar of [1, 2, 3]"
          ></span>
      </button>
      <a 
        routerLink="/"
        class="navbar-brand"
        >Recipe Book</a>
    </div>
    <div
      class="navbar-collapse"
      [class.collapse]="collapsed"
      (window:resize)="collapsed = true">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <a
            href="#"
            (click)="onClickRecipes($event)"
            >Recipes</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a 
            href="#"
            (click)="onClickShoppingList($event)"
            >Shopping List</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li appDropdown class="dropdown">
          <a
            href="#"
            class="dropdown-toggle"
            role="button"
            >Manage<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Save Data</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fetch Data</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

> header.component.ts

```js
import {
  Component,
  Output,
  EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

export enum EventSource {
    Recipes,
    ShoppingList
  }

@Component({
    selector: 'app-header',
    templateUrl: './header.component.html'
})
export class HeaderComponent {
  collapsed = true;

  @Output()
  menuFired = new EventEmitter<EventSource>();

  onClickRecipes = (event: Event) => {
    **console.log('This works');**
    event.preventDefault();
    this.menuFired.emit(EventSource.Recipes);
  }

  onClickShoppingList = (event: Event) => {
    **console.log('This works');**
    event.preventDefault();
    this.menuFired.emit(EventSource.ShoppingList);
  }
}
```

I've been banging my head against this for days and I just can't figure it out. It looks like it *should* work. I have similar setups in other places where it works fine.

Comment: this code all works as you'd intend it to. Something else is going wrong or you're not seeing the actual error. are the logging statements not even showing?

Comment: are there any other errors in the console?

Comment: @bryan60 no, the log statements don't show at all

Comment: @c_ogoo no, there are no other errors

Comment: you should try and make a stackblitz recreating the error... nothing is wrong in this code that I can see

Comment: Recreated on stackblitz and the logs fire: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-angular-8-click-event-not-being-received @bryan60

Comment: @c_ogoo you're right. I don't get it.

Comment: @bryan60 what else do you think might be going on?

Comment: stop and restart the dev server .. is there any error in the build?

Comment: can't say without being able to reproduce the error.  can always try restarting the ol dev server

Comment: @c_ogoo I've stopped and restarted many times. no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the 
[Working Exaxmple](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-example-for-stackoverflow?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I don't think so, because I'm listening to menuFired in the app-header component. That sets the property read by isRecipesSelected()  and isShoppingListSelected(). It has to be an *ngIf so the visibility changes based on that property.

Comment: @MikeCaputo Updated my answer with the stackblitz link.

Comment: @MikeCaputo Let me know, if it is not working for you?

Comment: it works on stackblitz, but what did you change? I can't tell.

Comment: Added this below line in the AppModule, and everything else is your coding only.
                   
schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out. It was not anything to do with the code itself, but with something I had done in app.module.ts. In @NgModule -> bootstrap, for some reason I had included HeaderComponent. I don't remember why I would have put it in there, but apparently that was suppressing events somehow. Thank you to everyone who tried to help; if I hadn't seen it working on stackblitz, it would never have occurred to me to check the app.module.

Comment: Can you accept my answer? if it (stackblitz example ) helped you?

Answer (score -1):

> Angular 8 Click event not being received

How about (click) ??

```
  <app-header
    (click)="onMenuFired($event)"
    ></app-header>
```

Comment: The click is being tracked in the header component. I want the app component to receive the custom event from the header so it gets the correct event data.

Comment: `onMenuFired` his custom event defined in his app-header component. He already implemented a click.